# How to compress files as password protected archive using Python

Tags: python, passwords, gzip, archive, zip

Is there a way to compress `gzip` or `zipfile` as a password protected archive?
Here is an example code illustrating how to archive file with no password protection:

```
import gzip, shutil

filepath = r'c:\my.log'

with gzip.GzipFile(filepath + ".gz", "w") as gz:
    with open(filepath) as with_open_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(with_open_file, gz)

import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath + '.zip', 'w')
zf.write(filepath)
zf.close()
```

Comment: So what you are asking for is siomeone else to read the manual for these functions?

Comment: [The gzip format does not support password protection](http://superuser.com/a/162625).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python supports [*extracting* password protected zips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366917/1016216):

```
zipfile.ZipFile('myarchive.zip').extractall(pwd='P4$$W0rd')
```

Sadly, it does not support creating them. You can either call an external tool like 7zip or use a third-party library like [this zlib wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyminizip/0.1.1).

Comment: While `pyminizip` could offer an easy solution for those who create the password protected archives it was very hard to install. Please let me know if you have a recommendation on how to install it on Windows for Python 2.7.

Comment: On Windows I would just install 7zip and call it from Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gpg for encryption](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/). That would be a separate wrapper around the archived and compressed data.

Comment: Would you be willing to post an example on how to encrypt the source data (a file or variable), archive it to a `zip` or `gzip` file, then un-archive it and decrypt producing the original uncompressed and decrypted source data.

Comment: First off, you got it backwards. You have to archive and compress _before_ encryption, not after. Encrypted data appears random and is not compressible. Second, look at the link for examples.

Comment: It is not working for me. I have installed it using `pip install python-gnupg`. Imported module with `import gnupg`. Then I try to initiate the instance with `gpg = gnupg.GPG('C:/temp')` which gives an error message I post below

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    gpg = gnupg.GPG('C:/temp')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg\gnupg.py", line 125, in __init__
    ignore_homedir_permissions=ignore_homedir_permissions,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py", line 181, in __init__
    self.homedir = os.path.expanduser(home) if home else _util._conf`

Comment: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_util.py", line 765, in __set__
    getattr(obj, self.fset.__name__)(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py", line 438, in _homedir_setter
    raise RuntimeError(str(ae))
RuntimeError: Homedir ''C:\temp\gnupghome\.config\python-gnupg'' needs read/write permissions`

Comment: @MarkAdler if you encrypt a compressed file, doesn't that lead to a vulnerability? The compressed file adheres to strict protocols on header, footer, etc. So a cracker would have some plain text from within your encrypted file to work with in the search for the password.

Comment: @hobs gpg precedes the compressed data with a small amount of random data before encryption for this reason.

Comment: @MarkAdler yes, but that just obsficates the location of the header in the encrypted text, it does not change the presence of the plaintext header itself. So a brute force attack would merely have to grep for the header within the trial and error decompressed files. Salting, I think, is an attempt to mitigate this vulnerability, but that does not change the fact that it is a vulnerability: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836684/623735